# How to sum the total in google spreadsheets based on a true/false column

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, sumifs

I am trying to make a list of sold items with this formula used to check it off:

```
=CONCATENATE(COUNTIF($A$3:$A$50,TRUE), "/", COUNTA($C$3:$C$50), " Items sold ")
```

I want each sold item to add up the prices in `column B` and put the total profit somewhere in the sheet.

Here is the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HyHbuugR0nzWctjcu4Zk6z8x3H6chQcjWHxvF-pRyAE/edit?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably:

```
=SUMIF(A3:A, TRUE, B3:B)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I did not see that. This website is weird on a tablet